# Mongodb cannot authenticate via commandline

Tags: mongodb

Having the strangest issue, and I've done this a million times before in other server environments. I can authenticate like so:

```
use admin
db.auth('user', 'pass')
```

This works fine and I can authenticate on the admin db. However I try this:

```
mongodump --authenticationDatabase admin -u user -p pass
```

It fails and the logs tell me `AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch`. I have no idea what is going on, but it's extremely annoying because I need to pass the username and password into the mongodump command in my backup script.

Comment: What versions are reported by `db.version` in the `mongo` shell and `mongodump --version` in your O/S shell? Does your password include any special characters (such as `$` or `@`) that might be interpreted by the O/S shell?

Comment: Same version, both are 3.2. There are special characters in the password(eg. $), though I thought enclosing the password in quotes would solve that issue, maybe not?